# Kendo Autocomplete search multiple columns

Tags: php, autocomplete, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i have used kendo Auto Complete in my KendoGrid,
It is working fine for now, but it only search or get data from across one column only,

i want it to search across multiple columns.

Here is my code of Autocomplete in KendoGrid.

```
 $(function(){
    $("#EmployeeGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource:{
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            pageSize: 5,
            transport: {
                read: "<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/hr_management/manage_hr/list_view"
            },
            schema:{
                data: "data",
                total: "total"
            }
        },
        toolbar: kendo.template($("#toolbarTemplate").html()),
        pageable: {
            input:true,
            numeric:false
        },
        columns: [
            {
                field: "EmployeeID",
                hidden:true
            },
            {
              field: "FileNo",
              title: "File Number"
            },
            {
                template:"#= FirstName # #= LastName #",
                title: "Full Name"
            },
            {
                field:"City",
                title:"City"
            },
            {
                field:"AddressLine1",
                title:"Address 1"
            },

            {
                field:"WorkPhone",
                title:"WorkPhone"
            },
            {
                field:"MobileNo",
                title:"Mobile No"
            },
            {command: { text: "View", click: showDetails }, title: " ", width: "140px"},
            {command: { text: "Edit", click: EditUserDetails }, title: " ", width: "140px"}
        ]
    });

});
var autoCompleteUsers = $("#employees").kendoAutoComplete({
    minLength: 3,
    dataTextField: "FileNo",
    dataSource: {
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/hr_management/manage_hr/search_employee/",
                data: function (arg){
                    return {FileNo : autoCompleteUsers.data("kendoAutoComplete").value()};
                }
            }
        }
    },
    change: onChangeAutoComplete
});
function onChangeAutoComplete(){
    var value = this.value();
    var grid = $('#EmployeeGrid');
    if (value) {
        grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({ field: "FileNo", operator: "Contains", value: value });
    } else {
        grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({});
    }
}


function showDetails(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.action_button').html('');
    var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
    var item = $("#EmployeeGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(row);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/hr_management/manage_hr/view_employee_profile/'?>"+JSON.parse(item.EmployeeID),
        success: function(output_string){
            var data = output_string.split("MyMark_Employee");
            $('.second_column_content_container').html(data[0]);
            $('.action_button').html(data[1]);

            $("#createEmployee").hide();
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("error");
        }
    });

}


function EditUserDetails(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.action_button').html('');
    var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
    var item = $("#EmployeeGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(row);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/hr_management/manage_hr/edit_employee_details/'?>"+JSON.parse(item.EmployeeID),
        success: function(output_string){
            var data = output_string.split("MyMark_Employee");
            $('.second_column_content_container').html(data[0]);
            if(data[1]!= " ")
            {
                $('.action_button').html(data[1]);
            }

        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("error");
        }
    });

}
```

What to do?
Do i need to define multiple `dataTextField:`?
Need Suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Good question. I wondered the same thing.

After looking at the Kendo code (kendo.web.min.js), it does not look like it is possible to define multiple fields for the property dataTextField. It looks like only one field is allowed.

A workaround is to add a field in your model that includes (in string form) all the fields that you want to search. Then set dataTextField to that field. It's not an ideal solution, but it works.